# Undefined reference to vtable in final class constructor and destructor

Tags: c++

Hello I am trying to learn c++ from a book "C++ an introduction to programming by Jesse Liberty and Jim Keogh" I am doing the questions for chapter 12 multiple inheritance. Q4 asks me to derive car and bus from vehicle with car as an adt and then derive `sportscar`, `wagon` and `coupe` from `car` and implement a non pure virtual function from `vehicle` in `car`. It is compiling on codelite but at build time it gives the error

> undefined reference to 'vtable for Coupe' on the constructor and destructor for `Coupe`

Please can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong so I can learn more about how to handle virtual function definitions correctly with vtables.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vehicle
{
public:
Vehicle(){};
virtual ~Vehicle(){};
virtual int GetItsSpeed() = 0;
int GetItsTyreSize();
virtual int GetItsRegistration() { return ItsRegistration; }
protected:
int ItsSpeed;
int ItsRegistration;
};

class Car : public Vehicle
{
public:
Car(){};
virtual ~Car(){};
virtual int GetItsSpeed() = 0;
int GetItsBootSize() { return ItsBootSize; }
int GetItsRegistration() { return ItsRegistration; }
virtual int GetItsRadioVolume() = 0;
int GetItsTyreSize() { return ItsTyreSize; }
protected:
int ItsBootSize;
int ItsRadioVolume;
int ItsTyreSize;
};

class Bus : public Vehicle
{
Bus(){};
~Bus(){};
public:
int GetItsSpeed() { return ItsSpeed; }
int GetItsPassengerSize() { return ItsPassengerSize; }
private:
int ItsPassengerSize;
};

class SportsCar : public Car
{
public:
SportsCar(){};
~SportsCar(){};
int GetItsSpeed() { return ItsSpeed; }
int GetItsPowerSteeringAccuracy() { return ItsPowerSteeringAccuracy; }
private:
int ItsPowerSteeringAccuracy;
};

class Wagon : public Car
{
public:
Wagon(){};
~Wagon(){};
int GetItsSpeed() { return ItsSpeed; }
int GetItsTrailerSize() { return ItsTrailerSize; }
private:
int ItsTrailerSize;
};

class Coupe : public Car
{
public:
Coupe(){ ItsTyreSize = 10; }
~Coupe(){};
int GetItsSpeed();
int GetItsInteriorStyle() { return ItsInteriorStyle; }
int GetItsRadioVolume() { return ItsRadioVolume; }
private:
int ItsInteriorStyle;
};

void startof()
{
Coupe MariesCoupe;
cout << "Maries Coupe has a tyre size of "
<< MariesCoupe.GetItsTyreSize() << " .\n\n";

}

int main()
{
startof();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems fine here: http://ideone.com/NTxKcK

Answer (score 2):

You should implement `GetItsSpeed` in `Coupe`.
For example,

```
int Coupe::GetItsSpeed() {return 0;};
```